# Where is Fred the miniboss?

Tags: across-the-obelisk

I've been achievement hunting and one of my last achievements is to kill Fred the miniboss. He looks like a dragonkin and so presumably should be found somewhere in the blue portal but I swear I've checked every node and never encountered him.

Where is he?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### He's at the Mansion node in the blue portal.

Naturally after posting this question I blundered into him by sheer luck. He can be found at the Mansion node at the far east of the blue portal, but you don't *have* to fight him there. If you check upstairs or in other parts of the mansion (for example, if you have Gustav as a member or are recruiting him) you will not encounter Fred.